# What are the solutions for saving data from Android to SQL Server?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, web-services

I would know how many and which are the possibile system for saving data from android application to remote sql server. I know just one way: Web service. Are there other systems?

Answer (score 0):

I myself use PHP scripts and HTTP Requests. You do not want to have the app establish a direct connection to the server, because that would require database usernames and passwords sotred in the app. Use POST or GET methods to post data, and then in the PHP, echo out the results of the script and then decode them in your app.

Answer (score 0):

REST + JSON. Check them out:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer
and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON